# magento how do i create specific home page for specific templates

Tags: magento, layout, themes

I have a good design on my website and i suddenly realized my design does not render pretty well in internet explorer 7 and 8, i tried all that i can but i still cannot fix it and i dont like how its displaying in those browsers so i decided to add exception on the design configuration coumn by adding `MSIE 7.0` and then value of defaul, tested with internet explorer 7 and it works well but my problem is that my custom theme has some large images and texts and other materials that were aligned nicely with css but once i changed the theme to default and it does not see those css, they also just display anyhow and its really a pain for me, all that i need to do now is find a way to make the default theme load with a different cms page instead of the normal homepage for my main theme. i dont know if i can do that but i need some little help or guide to go about it.

I followed your guide and have created the files and now i can see the welspot template under the design field.

Now i need to still use the old homepage (the one i have installed with the hellowired theme), i want to copy magento default theme into my package now and edit it but i need to find a way to remove all the static blocks i created through maybe a layout file as i wont use those blocks in the default theme and even if possible add different images through xml so i would be using two themes with the same homepage but dynamic content based on the theme being used.

Comment: your question is very mixed, what you want to do? Do you want to show a CMS page in Home Page, or do you want to make a CMS page to default home page? Or, do you want to add a special css file into default home page? What it is?

Comment: Thanks for checking out my question. i am currently using the hellowired theme and as you guessed i have added static contents and stactic blocks all over the cms homepage as requested by hellowired installation guide, you can check the site at http://www.welspot.com. Because there are static blocks and contents in my homepage, if i switch to a different theme, my images and contents outputs without any styling.so i want to know if there is a way for me to assign a different cms homepage to the magento default theme or even rewrite the magento default theme to display properly with layouts

Comment: Dear Jean, I can't tell you where it is those static blocks, you should check xml file. The best way, go to Admin > System > Configuration > Developer section then enable "Template Path Hints". You will see which template and layout xml files loaded in page render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can set default home page whatever you create but you should do some things.

First, create **config.xml**

```
<!-- path: app/code/local/Welspot/Page/etc/config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Welspot_Page>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Welspot_Page>
</modules>
<global>
    <page>
    <layouts>
        <welspot_one_column_cms module="page" translate="label">
        <label>Welspot One Column</label>
        <template>page/welspot_one_column.phtml</template>
        <layout_handle>welspot_one_column_cms</layout_handle>
        </welspot_one_column_cms>
    </layouts>
    </page>
</global>
</config>
```

Second, create **Welspot_Page.xml**

```
<!-- path : /app/etc/modules -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Welspot_Page>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Welspot_Page>
</modules>
 </config>
```

Third, create **welspot_one_column.phtml**

```
<!-- path : /app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/page -->
<div>Hello World</div>
```

As you might guess, you should customize welspot_one_column.phtml file.

Finally, go to `Admin > CMS > Pages > Home Page > Design Tab` select your newly created template (Welspot One Column).

Comment: Thank you very much @oguz-celikdemir, i've never had a detailed explanation to a problem more than you've shown me today, i really appreciate you helping me on. i edited my post and added more explanation to it. Sorry as i have a very bad english. Thanks again

Comment: I think there's a missing </config> in your config.xml but otherwise that worked perfectly for me too. Thanks!