# Magento Module for new CMS layout, but in version 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento

I'm trying to simply create a new layout option for a CMS page in Magento.  I've followed the [instructions here on the Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates) to create a module and it does not work.  When I make the same addition to the actual core config.xml file, it works fine, but not as a custom module.  Based on some research it looks like this would have worked in Magento 1.6, but does not work on 1.7, I'm trying to figure out why.  I have the following:

**app/etc/modules/Fruit_Banana.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Fruit_Banana>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Fruit_Banana>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Fruit/Banana/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Fruit_Banana>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fruit_Banana>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <homepage_middle translate="label">
          <label>Homepage</label>
          <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>homepage_one</layout_handle>
        </homepage_middle>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't seem to be working as a module?  I am using version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Does Magento recognize your module as installed?

Comment: It does list the module as enabled in the Admin > Config > Advanced > Advanced page.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You problem seems like Magento not seeing the module (which was sort of true in the end) For what it's worth, my module list module (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/module-list.html) performs a similar function, but also checks for missing etc/config.xml files and code pool conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seems like I messed up!  It does in fact work in 1.7, my problem was I had the filename for config.xml spelled confix.xml

Once I adjusted that, the custom layout popped right up!  Thanks to those that chimed in.

Answer (score 1):

The `local` modules should be in the `code` directory

`app/code/local/Fruit/Banana/etc/config.xml`

and not in the `core` directory as you mentioned

`app/code/core/local/Fruit/Banana/etc/config.xml`

Comment: That was a mistake on my part (fixed in my main question), I do in fact have it in:

app/code/local/Fruit/Banana/etc/config.xml

But it does not work...

Comment: Ohh that's great. Please check this, it might help you: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1406/P30/

Comment: check the accepted answer of this post, it will definitely help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960472/magento-how-do-i-create-specific-home-page-for-specific-templates