# Magento adding new page layout for category use

Tags: xml, magento-1.7

I have a category in my store that requires a totally different layout to the standard Magento layouts. So I created a new copy of the 1column.phtml and renaked it and made one small change to test:

**frontend/test/default/template/page/1column-lookbook.phtml**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="container">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="page_content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sixcol">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="sixcol last">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"><h3>Filter here</h3></div>
            <div class="row"><h3>Scrolling content</h3></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't however seem to get this to be seen by my category, I've tried adding a reference to it in the page.xml and layout.xml files. But no matter what I've tried I can't seem to get it to display int he page layout drop down for my categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search in magento for the "1column.phtml" string you would find:

**App/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml**
*On line 45 you will find the config you need*

**Now you can put the same config structure in your own module like this:**

```
<global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <test module="page" translate="label">
                <label>The test</label>
                <template>page/test.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>page_test</layout_handle>
            </test>
        </layouts>
    </page>
</global>
```

Refresh the magento cache and go to your category edit screen => custom design => page layout and select the template you just added in the dropdown.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Magento Module for new CMS layout, but in version 1.7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802189/magento-module-for-new-cms-layout-but-in-version-1-7-0-2)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/285425/#t400446

plenty out there on this..

In your custom module XML config add some entries to add your new layout

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <page>
        <layouts>
            <my_layout module="page" translate="label">
                <label>My Layout</label>
                <template>page/mylayout.phtml</template>
                <layout_handle>my_layout</layout_handle>
            </my_layout>
        ....
```

don't forget to refresh your cache after

Comment: Both of those are specifically for CMS pages, would that also add the to be usable by categories as well?

Answer (score 0):

Find: /App/etc/local.xml

Just before `</global>` tag, put the extra page layout config.

```
<page>
  <layouts>
    <lookbook module="page" translate="label">
      <label>LOOK BOOK</label>
        <template>page/1column-lookbook.phtml</template>
      <layout_handle>page_lookbook</layout_handle>
    </lookbook>
  </layouts>
</page>
```

Thats'it. :)

Comment: How to add multiple custom layouts in magento?

Answer (score -1):

So better way it to create a new layout.

http://www.sundataplus.com/adding-a-new-page-layout-to-magento-1-x/

The file can be edited: app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml
Add new lines between .. along with other layouts.

```
<page>
        <layouts>
.
.
        <home module="page" translate="label">
            <label>Home</label>
            <template>page/home.phtml</template>
            <layout_handle>page_home</layout_handle>
        </home>
.
.
        </layouts>
</page>
```

Create new file : template/page/home.phtml along with 1column.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml etc.. You can just copy the existing code of one of the column layout phtml inside the home.phtml. Modify the code inside home.phtml as per your need.